# Do we really need Eureka service in Docker Swarm?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have multiple docker service's running in Swarm environment. 
Also I have created overlay network and using service name
to API call's between Service A -> Service B.

Is using Eureka is advantage in swarm cluster?  Why can't we just use consistent service name and port to call between all services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any need to use Eureka if all services are on the same overlay network.

If services outside the overlay network are required, Eureka can be useful.